# Is there an integration between floweaver and matplotlib to plot sankey diagrams onto an ax?

Tags: python, matplotlib, sankey-diagram

Is there a simple way to generate a Sankey plot using floweaver onto an ax or figure in matplotlib? My only idea so far is saving the floweaver plot as a PNG and then load it into an ax with `ax.imshow('...')` Are there common workarounds? The matplotlib sankey functionality is not what I am looking for.